# jacobian polynomial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abstract-algebra

Here is the question which could be quit difficult (but could be not):

Let $C$ be a field of complex numbers and $f \in C[x,y]$ be a polynomial such that there exist
$g \in C[x,y]$ and $Jac(f,g) \in C^{*}$ i.e. determinant of Jacobian matrix of polynomials $f$ and $g$
is a nonzero constant.
Question:  Is it true that $f$ is irreducible?

Any comments are welcome!

Answer (score 5):

Edit: The statement in the next paragraph is wrong! I misunderstood the result of Kaliman: it says that given $(f,g)$ as in the question, there is a polynomial automorphism $\phi$ of $\mathbb{C}^2$ such that each fiber of $\phi \circ (f,g): \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$ is irreducible. So I would assume it is still hard to give a positive answer to the question, but clearly what I wrote below is false.

I would assume the question is quite difficult, since a positive answer would imply the Jacobian conjecture by  [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1993-117-01/S0002-9939-1993-1106179-7/S0002-9939-1993-1106179-7.pdf) result of Kaliman.